# How to add large number of columns to Ionic grid?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a table structure which has 13 columns in a single row. I am using ionic for my project in which grid is used. When i add 13 columns their text overlap with each other. Do we have a better way to handle this scenario in ionic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic is primarily to build mobile application. I don't think that have 13 columns displayed on a small screen will be a good idea. I would consider changing layout/UI to avoid 13 columns

May be one row will include several lines, so that the data is stacked.